# Is there always a prime $p$ so that the largest prime factor of $p^2+i$ not exceeding $p$ for $-k\leq i \leq k$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-factorization

Define $f(n)$=the largest prime factor of $n$. For example, $f(28)=7.$

> ***Question:*** Is it true that for any given integer $k>0$, we can find a prime $p>\sqrt k$ so that 
>   $$f(p^2-k)\leq p,f(p^2-k+1)\leq p,\dots,f(p^2+k)\leq p~?$$

For example, if $k=6,$ we can take $p=660683,$ since $\{f(660683^2+i)\mid i=-6,-5,\dots,5,6\}=\{76493,53441,132137,278413,19289,55057,660683,614333,73483,43177,3049,273929,171553\}.$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 7, 499, 7079, 8663, ...; not apparently in the OEIS.

Comment: In other words, given $k$, you want $p$ such that the $2k+1$ numbers around $p^2$, namely $p^2 - k$ to $p^2 + k$, are all made up only of prime factors at most $p$. Is this reading correct?

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Absolutely right.

Comment: 7, 499, 7079, 8663, 660683, 660683, ...

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a proof, but I do have a heuristic argument that the statement is true, as well as some asymptotic estimates on the size of $p$ as a function of $k$.

First, define an [**unusual number**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unusual_number) to be a number $n$ whose largest prime factor is strictly greater than $\sqrt{n}$.  One of the requirements in your question is related to unusual numbers:

**Proposition.**  *Let $k\geq 0$ be an integer, let $p \geq \dfrac{k-3}{4}$ be an odd prime, and suppose that the set*
$$
\{p^2-k,\;p^2-k+1,\;\ldots,\;p^2+k\}
$$
*contains no unusual numbers.  Then no element of this set is divisible by any prime number greater than $p$.*

*Proof:* Let $n$ be an element of the set, and let $q$ be the largest prime number dividing $n$.  Since $n$ is not unusual, we know that
$$
q \;\leq\; \sqrt{n} \;\leq\; \sqrt{p^2+k} \;\leq\; \sqrt{p^2+4p+3} \;<\; \sqrt{p^2+4p+4} \;=\; p+2.
$$
Since $q$ is prime and $q < p+2$, it follows that $q\leq p$.$\quad\square$

Now, [this paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022404993900939) by John G. Kemeny gives asymptotic estimates on the frequency of unusual numbers.  Specifically, if $u(n)$ denotes the number of unusual numbers less than or equal to $n$, then Kemeny proves
$$\
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{u(n)}{n} \;=\; \log 2.
$$
That is, the probability that a given number is unusual is about $\log 2 \approx 69.31\%$.  (Note: This result had previously been announced by [Schroeppel](http://www.inwap.com/pdp10/hbaker/hakmem/number.html#item29) in an unpublished 1972 memo, but Kemeny's paper seems to be the first published proof.)

Thus, roughly speaking, the probability that the set
$$
\{p^2-k,p^2-k+1,\ldots,p^2+k\}
$$
has no unusual numbers is $(1-\log 2)^{2k}$.  This value does not depend on $p$, so eventually there ought to be a prime number $p$ for which the corresponding set is free of unusual numbers.

Of course, such heuristic reasoning should always be taken with a grain of salt.  Similar heuristic arguments can be made for the [Twin Prime Conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_prime) and [Goldbach's Conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach%27s_conjecture), and these are major open problems.

By the way, the reasoning above gives us some rough estimates on how large $p$ needs to be as a function of $k$.  In particular, given a value of $k$, there ought to be (with $>50\%$ chance) a corresponding value of $p$ somewhere in the first $(1-\log 2)^{-2k}\log 2$ primes.  This predicts that there should  to be a value for $k=7$ in the first $11$ million primes, and a value for $k=8$ in the first $112$ million primes.

**Edit:** After a lengthy computer search, I have found that $83\text{,}323\text{,}327$ works for $k=7$, and $383\text{,}155\text{,}211$ works for $k=8$.  (Primes for $k=1,\ldots,6$ were given in the comments above.)  These numbers are the $4\text{,}851\text{,}928$'th and $20\text{,}485\text{,}208$'th primes, respectively, which agrees roughly with the asymptotic predictions above, although both arrived a bit early.  The prediction for $k=9$ is that it will be satisfied by one of the first $1.2$ billion primes.

Comment: The "a bit early" part might be related to the observation that a number $p^2-1$ is always $p$-smooth (since $p$ is an odd prime) and $p^2-4$ would not be $p$-smooth only if $p$ was the lower part of a twin prime pair; a pretty rare event on its own.